# Calculating differences between next decreasing values

Tags: r, dataframe, sequence

I would like to calculate the difference between the values when the sequences decreases. Is there any function counting this? Because I can't find anything similar on the web.

My example:

```
data.frame(x=c("0", "0", "2", "2","3", "0", "4", "0", "1"), 
           diff=c("0","0", "0", "0", "0","3", "0", "4", "0"))

  x diff
1 0    0
2 0    0
3 2    0
4 2    0
5 3    0
6 0    3
7 4    0
8 0    4
9 1    0
```

Comment: `c(NA, pmax(x[-length(x)] - x[-1], 0))`
Sotos' answer is nicer.

Comment: I get `[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA`

Comment: Most likely b/c your columns are character columns. Try to convert it to a numeric first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply find the difference, negate it and replace all negative values(showing increase of data) to 0

```
#convert to numeric first
dd[] <-lapply(dd, function(i)as.numeric(as.character(i)))

replace(-diff(dd$x), -diff(dd$x) < 0 ,  0)
#[1] 0 0 0 0 3 0 4 0
```

If you have NAs, then one way to handle them is to make them equal to the previous value, i.e.

```
x <- c(5, NA, 2) #Notice how I DON'T put them in quotes so it's numeric
x1 <- replace(x, is.na(x), x[which(is.na(x)) - 1])

#Using the same method as above on the new x1,
c(0, replace(-diff(x1), - diff(x1) < 0, 0))
#[1] 0 0 3
```

Comment: Also I get `[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA`

Comment: Convert to numeric first

Comment: Suppose I have an empty value `NA` in data frame. Will it count well then?

Comment: It will give NAs after the NA value. How do you treat them? Do you want to remove them, convert to 0?...It depends on what you want to do with them

Comment: When I have `x=c("5", "NA", "2")` I would like get `diff=c("0", "0", "3")`.

Answer (score 2):

Another way using `diff`

```
inds <- c(0, diff(df$x))
-inds * (inds < 0)
#[1] 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 4 0
```

**data**

```
df <- type.convert(df)
```